# Is it possible to use python to detect when Difference Boolean hides a mesh?

Tags: python, boolean-modifier

I have an enormous mesh (200mb) and a collection of small meshes that I apply as Boolean difference modifiers to it. Sometimes a modifier causes the original mesh to disappear, and I am trying to detect that with python. Currently my script applies separate loose parts after the Boolean and checks the number of objects to determine if it succeeded.  This works, but it is very slow. Is there another way for python to determine if the Boolean modifier caused the mesh to disappear?

Additional Info:
There are no doubles in the mesh.
Selecting Self-Intersection through the Blender GUI crashes my machine with an out of memory error.

Comment: you could check the number of vertices of the resulting mesh. But i i am not sure whether this is quicker....

Comment: You may check if etiehr your base mesh or your boolean cutters is non-manifold. A mesh can be non-manifold an have perfect topology, for example if you deleted a face and forgot to add it back

Comment: @ Chris, Thanks!  That is indeed faster.